# Change 'The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.' message

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am a new Drupal user. I constantly get this error message and I am aware of the reason behind this. Basically this is because of the SQL state 4000 error which is also called as SQL deadlock error. While I try to fix this issue, I would like to see if there is a way to change the text of this error --

**"The Website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later" .**

My question is pretty straight. I want to change this text to a meaningful one. Is it possible to do?Any guidelines on the steps to follow?

Answer (score 0):

This error page is not something that is easy for Drupal to control. It's usually produced by a 500 response from the server. But, I have managed to do this on one of my websites using a [service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers).

1. Create a custom HTML page for your new 500 error splash page.
2. Create a basic service worker that caches this page and returns it in the case of a 500 error.

Example:

```js
const filesToCache = [
  '/500.html'
];

const staticCacheName = '0.0';

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName)
    // Cache all of the configured files.
    .then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
    // Force an update of the service worker, if need be.
    .then(function() {
      return self.skipWaiting();
    })
  );
});

// Delete outdated cache.
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  const cacheWhitelist = [staticCacheName];
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});

// Serve appropriate error pages from cache.
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
    .then(response => {
      if (response) {
        return response;
      }
      return fetch(event.request)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 500) {
          return caches.match('/500.html');
        }

        return caches.open(staticCacheName)
      });
    })
  );
});
```

3. Add your service worker to the `<body>` of your `html.html.twig` file of your theme (or another comparable place):

```html
<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
        .then(swReg => {
          console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error('Service Worker Error', err);
        });
      });
    }
  </script>
```